# Apache tomcat : URL based redirection partially works

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, web-applications

I am working on deploying multiple webapps in single tomcat instance in which the webapp to be called depends upon the `URL` the user has called. So if user calls `www.domain-one.com`, then `firstapp.war` is the webapp the user is looking for and that will be shown to the user.

I have had partial luck with this. Right now, if I call `www.domain-one.com`, nothing happens, but if I call `www.domain-one.com/firstapp`, then correct webapp is called.

**I just want to get rid of that firstapp in the context-path.**  How can I achieve that.

Here is my config :

```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
        <Host name="www.domain-one.com" autodeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="/war/firstapp"/>
        <Host name="www.domain-two.com" autodeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="/war/secondapp"/>
        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

There are only two webapps for now in my webapps folder, neither a ROOT.war. I hope this information is enough. Kindly let me know why is this problem happening. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your tomcat majour release, check here:

Tomcat 6 - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Tomcat 7 - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Tomcat 8 - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

It's really straightforward and let's you get rid of the context path too.

Comment: Thank you sir... I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different config which solved this problem :

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
    <Host name="firstdomain.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="firstdomain_webapps">
            <Alias>www.firstdomain.com</Alias>
            <Context path=""/>
    </Host>

    <Host name="seconddomain.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="seconddomain_webapps">
            <Alias>www.seconddomain.com</Alias>
            <Context path=""/>
    </Host>
```

This config worked for me, and solved my problem.